# Issues with git branch checkout due to untracked working tree files

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I thought I put the days of Xcode + git issues behind me. Guess not. I am getting this git error when trying to checkout another branch.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    RCAlpha.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/andrewjl.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
    RCAlpha.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/andrewjl.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/RCAlpha.xcscheme
    RCAlpha.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/andrewjl.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Very well I say, let me remove these files:

```
andrewjl$ git rm --cached RCAlpha.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/andrewjl.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
fatal: pathspec 'RCAlpha.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/andrewjl.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate' did not match any files
```

At this point I'm not sure what to do. These files are all listed in my `.gitignore` and I also gave `git clean -f -d` a try as well. No dice. Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The files are untracked: `git rm --cached` cannot find them because there are not in the index. Just delete them, using your file manager or `rm`. Then checkout should work as expected. Note that `git status` will show you what git sees the files as (tracked, changed, untracked; with an additional option it will also display ignored files).

Answer (score 5):

they arent in git but there locally .. that means when you switch those would be lost and git doesnt allow that

remove them locally:

```
rm RCAlpha.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/andrewjl.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate RCAlpha.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/andrewjl.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/RCAlpha.xcscheme RCAlpha.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/andrewjl.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
```

they are recreated by xcode anyway. nothing important in there!

Comment: so how do I get it back? I have deleted it and now i can't pull from another branch.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

git rm --cache */xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist

git commit -m "Good bye xcschememanagement.plist"

Answer (score 1):

Git stash and git checkout "yourBranch"

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately in this case there will be no local changes to stash.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clean -f
```

solve the problem for me, they are untracked files when run clean they get remove.